# Split large string into substrings

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have a huge string like

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLM...
```

and I would like to split it into substrings of length 5 in this way:

```
>1
ABCDE
>2
BCDEF
>3
CDEFG
[...]
```

Answer (score 31):

> ```
> ${string:position:length}
> ```
>
> Extracts `$length` characters of substring from `$string` at
> `$position`.
>
> ```
> stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
> #       0123456789.....
> #       0-based indexing.
>
> echo ${stringZ:0}          # abcABC123ABCabc
> echo ${stringZ:1}          # bcABC123ABCabc
> echo ${stringZ:7}          # 23ABCabc
>
> echo ${stringZ:7:3}        # 23A
>                            # Three characters of substring.
> ```

*-- from [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide by Mendel Cooper*

Then use a loop to go through and add 1 to the position to extract each substring of length 5.

```
end=$(( ${#stringZ} - 5 ))
for i in $(seq 0 $end); do
    echo ${stringZ:$i:5}
done
```

Answer (score 25):

`fold -w5` should do the trick.

```
$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | fold -w5
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWXY
Z
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 19):

sed can do it in one shot:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqr"|sed -r 's/(.{5})/\1 /g'
abcde fghij klmno pqr
```

or

depends on your needs:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqr"|sed -r 's/(.{5})/\1\n/g' 
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqr
```

**update**

i thought it was just simply split string problem, didn't read the question very carefully. Now it should give what you need:

still one shot, but with awk this time:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqr"|awk '{while(length($0)>=5){print substr($0,1,5);gsub(/^./,"")}}'

abcde
bcdef
cdefg
defgh
efghi
fghij
ghijk
hijkl
ijklm
jklmn
klmno
lmnop
mnopq
nopqr
```

Comment: hmmm I do not know why but I am getting only abcde, the rest is not printed

Comment: what's your awk version? (awk --version) it should work with gawk. try replace awk with gawk. or nawk if you are on a Sun unix box.

Comment: thanks, with gawk is working ok, however for my huge string is still to slow - but I am working on to speed this up

Answer (score 2):

...or use the `split` command:

```
$ ls

$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqr" | split -b5

$ ls
xaa  xab  xac  xad

$ cat xaa
abcde
```

`split` also operates on files...

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
s=ABCDEFGHIJ
for (( i=0; i < ${#s}-4; i++ )); do 
  printf ">%d\n%s\n" $((i+1)) ${s:$i:5}
done
```

outputs

```
>1
ABCDE
>2
BCDEF
>3
CDEFG
>4
DEFGH
>5
EFGHI
>6
FGHIJ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str=ABCDEFGHIJKLM
splitfive(){ echo "${1:$2:5}" ; }
for (( i=0 ; i < ${#str} ; i++ )) ; do splitfive "$str" $i ; done
```

Or, perhaps you want to do something more intelligent with the results

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

splitstr(){
    printf '%s\n' "${1:$2:$3}"
}

n=$1
offset=$2

declare -a by_fives

while IFS= read -r str ; do
    for (( i=0 ; i < ${#str} ; i++ )) ; do
            by_fives=("${by_fives[@]}" "$(splitstr "$str" $i $n)")
    done
done

echo ${by_fives[$offset]}
```

And then call it

```
$ split-by 5 2 <<<"ABCDEFGHIJKLM"
CDEFG
```

You can adapt it from there.

EDIT: trivial version in C, for performance comparison:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE* f;
    int n=0;
    char five[6];

    five[5] = '\0';

    f = fopen("inputfile", "r");

    if(f!=0){
            fread(&five, sizeof(char), 5, f);
            while(!feof(f)){
                    printf("%s\n", five);
                    fseek(f, ++n, SEEK_SET);

                    fread(&five, sizeof(char), 5, f);
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Forgive my bad C, I really don't knw the language.

Comment: Thanks! your first idea is ok, but for my purposes is extremely slow... I have very huge string - 10^8 characters... so dividing it into substrings takes  lot of time...

Comment: @didymos: It depends on what you're actually doing and whether you want to process each set, find a particular offset, or what have you. What is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Would sed do it?:

```
$ sed 's/\(.....\)/\1\n/g' < filecontaininghugestring
```

Comment: `sed 's/...../&\n/g' filename` is sufficient, but doesn't solve the problem (and also requires that `\n` be understood, which not all `sed` implementaions can do).

Answer (score 1):

sed can do it:

```
 sed -nr ':a;h;s/(.{5}).*/\1/p;g;s/.//;ta;' <<<"ABCDEFGHIJKLM" | # split string
     sed '=' | sed '1~2s/^/>/' # add line numbers and insert '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` and specify **characters** instead of **fields**, and then change output delimiter to whatever you need, like new line:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" | cut --output-delimiter=$'\n' -c1-5,6-10,11-15
```

output

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
```

or

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" | cut --output-delimiter=$':' -c1-5,6-10,11-15
```

output

```
ABCDE:FGHIJ:KLMNO
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you guys I was able to find a way to do this fast! This is my solution combining a few ideas from here:

```
str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"   
splitfive(){
    echo $1 | cut -c $2- | sed -r 's/(.{5})/\1\n/g'
}  
for (( i=0; i <= 5; i++ )); do
    splitfive "$str" $i
done | grep -v "^$"
```

---

*[The above answer was initially added to the question itself. Here are the relevant comments.]*

> Your `splitfive` could be more efficient. There's no need to pipe to cut, in bash you could say `cut -c "$2"- <<<"$1" | sed` etc and it will be slightly better. -- [sorpigal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180736/sorpigal) Sep 28 '11 at 11:48

> Your sed expression could also be improved to `sed 's/...../&\n/g'` which executes about twice as fast. -- [sorpigal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180736/sorpigal) Sep 28 '11 at 11:56

Comment: This doesn't actually produce the desired result. The question says `ABCDE`, `BCDEF`... but this produces `ABCDE`, `FGHIJ`...