# How to format a base64 encoded string to jslintable lines of x characters?

Tags: javascript, base64, converters, line-breaks, jslint

I have to lint a number of files which include images as base64 strings.

Of course I can break them into the correct line format by hand, but...

**Question**:
Are there any online converters which break strings into "JavaScript usable" lines of n characters? I was trying to use the website [textmechanic](http://textmechanic.co/Add-Remove-Line-Breaks.html) but it will still require me to wrap lines in `"[line]" +` which becomes cumbersome rather quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: `/*jslint maxlen: 0 */`? Or is there a business reason you have to fix those lines to be less than `x` characters long? I mean, if you can't `maxlen`, there are lots of ways to break lines into smaller lines, but I'm not sure I understand your constraints -- why would an "online converter" be better than, say, PowerShell or [a {modified version of this} bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568112/split-large-string-into-substrings)?

Comment: maxlen must be 80, no exceptions (company policy). Of course I can split the string into lines of [n] characters, but then I still need to manually touch every line twice to add leading quotation mark plus trailing quotation mark plus plus to go from `dasdasda` to `"dasdasda" +`. So I was wondering if there was a script to split and properly wrap

Answer (score -1):

Check out this online tool, http://textmechanic.co/Line-Length-Breaker.html
It will definitely help you out.

Comment: I did link to textmechanic above, but this looks interesting. thanks!

Comment: ***This answer should be deleted.***  It is a link-only answer, and the link has gone bad (as is the risk of link-only answers).